# In Inno Setup how to save user inputs to registry?

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

This is what I'm trying to figure out, in Inno Setup I want the installer to get

1. User's name (manual input)
2. Birthday (manual input)

And both of those i want to use as variable to save it in registry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just combine answers to these questions:

- [Adding user completed form to Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13661364/850848)
- [Inno Setup [Registry] - Using function return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37700989/850848) or [Inno Setup: How to pass variable from [Code] to [Run] (or other section)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19299669/850848)

They show you how to use the [`CreateInputQueryPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputquerypage) and [scripted constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to get a code like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "UserName"; 
    ValueData: "{code:GetUserName}"
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "UserBirthday"; \
    ValueData: "{code:GetUserBirthday}"
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  UserInputsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  
function GetUserName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[0];
end;
  
function GetUserBirthday(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[1];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'User information', 'User name and birthday',
      'Please specify the following information, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage.Add('Name:', False);
  UserInputsPage.Add('Birthday:', False);
end;
```

[image: User name and birthday page]

This will create a registry key like:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\My Company\My Program]
"UserName"="John Doe"
"UserBirthday"="1975-05-02"
```